# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:unable to resolve

Tags: java

I am facing the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://xyz.abc.com
```

I have tried all possible solutions mentioned in many forums, but still unable to connect.

```
   try{
    URLConnection openConnection = new URL("https://xyz.abc.com").openConnection();
    openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
    InputStream is = openConnection.getInputStream();

    InputSource source = new InputSource(is);

} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("---ee---" + e);
    throw e;
}
```

Another trial:

```
 URL obj = new URL("https://xyz.abc.com");
                HttpURLConnection connection = ((HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection());
                connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
                System.out.println("--connection.getResponseCode() --" + connection.getResponseCode() );//403
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Do i need to install some certificates(not sure).

--EDITED--

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class Test {
    public static void disableCertificateValidation() {

        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new X509Certificate[0];
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                }};

        // Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            disableCertificateValidation();
            try {
                URL obj = new URL("https://xyz.abc.com");
                HttpURLConnection connection = ((HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection());
                connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
                System.out.println("--connection.getResponseCode() --" + connection.getResponseCode() ); //403 
                InputStream input;
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200)  // this must be called before 'getErrorStream()' works
                input = connection.getInputStream();
            else {
                input = connection.getErrorStream();
                System.out.println("in error stream : " + input);
            }
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                String msg;
                while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
    }
}
```

output:

```
--connection.getResponseCode() --403
in error stream : sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@685cb137
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2Fview%2Ftools%2Fjob%2FMISC.DefectSummaryReport%2FlastSuccessfulBuild%2Fartifact'/><script>window.location.replace('/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2Fview%2Ftools%2Fjob%2FMISC.DefectSummaryReport%2FlastSuccessfulBuild%2Fartifact');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

Comment: That response comes from your server.  You need to figure out why the server is sending that response.

Comment: Does a GET request work from cURL / a browser from same terminal?

Comment: 403 == FORBIDDEN. You need to provide credentials. https://httpstatuses.com/403

Comment: @Alfabravo - Yes it works from URL.

Comment: @jiveturkey - After providing the credentials also i faced the same exception.

Comment: what is the response code when you access the website directly from browser? If it needs mutual SSL, yes you have install SSL certificate. But, you need to use `HttpsURLConnection` over `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: @harshavmb - When accessing directly i can open the URL(200).I have tried HttpsURLConnection too, but its same exception.which SSL certificate need to be installed and how, can u redirect to any examples in java.thanks

Comment: Can you try this ? 
`HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
        httpsConn.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure(0, null));
        httpsConn.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
    }`

Comment: The above code snippet disable SSL for testing purposes

Comment: @harshavmb - It's not recognizing SSLCertificateSocketFactory, i have downloaded javax-ssl-1_1.jar, but still not recognizing the class.I am working on windows platform.

Comment: @harshavmb - I have tried the example from http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/, but still facing the same exception.Unable to find out the solution for this scenario.

Comment: Can you try this https://pastebin.com/8E9yeJuZ? It worked for me in one of the bad certificate scenarios. Just add the method and call. Don't change anything. When accessed from browser, have you seen `Insecure Connection` warning?

Comment: These certificate issues are difficult to fix and will take sweet time to resolve. There could be n number of reasons blocking.

Comment: @harshavmb - When accessed https://pastebin.com/8E9yeJuZ, it said This site cant be reached. Can you post the code here.Thanks.

Comment: `public static void disableCertificateValidation() {
     // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
     TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
       new X509TrustManager() {
         public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
           return new X509Certificate[0]; 
         }
         public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
         public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
     }};` 
// to-be-contined..

Comment: `// Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
     HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
       public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
     };

     // Install the all-trusting trust manager
     try {
       SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
       sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
       HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
       HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
     } catch (Exception e) {}
   }`   --oo--end--oo--

Comment: @harshavmb - thanks.Code is showing error near X509TrustManager. It says Anonymous class derived from X509TrustManagermust either declared abstract or implement abstract method checkServerTrusted(..) in X509TrustManager. ANd another error is cannot resolve symbol secureRandom()

Comment: Have you imported from `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` or `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate` ? Import only from `java.security.cert` package. Am not seeing no errors using java8

Comment: @harshavmb - Yes , please see the post, i have added my code.Still showing the same errors as mentioned above.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you should have both... :( So, imports in my IDE :
`import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;` errors should get resolved now

Comment: Yes, errors got resolved.Now shall i place my old code?thanks@harshavmb

Comment: Yes, you can. Call this method in the beginning from your code.

Comment: @harshavmb - please see my edited post. Still getting the same response code(403), i have given comple output.thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access jenkins url? I don't know about the control groups setup.

Comment: Yes,i'm trying to access Jenkins URL, by default it takes my domain credentials. @harshavmb

Comment: okies. I don't know about your configuration. Good luck!

Comment: ok.Thanks, appreciate your help.@harshavmb

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code :

`openConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");`

Comment: I tried but the same exception, as i told i had googled and tried many examples given online but nothing had worked.